# Rails Application.css empty when changing from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, windows-7, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to switch my Rails code from Windows to Ubuntu, and the css files have stopped working. It's the same version of the code, and the same version of rails. The only major difference that I can think of is that the Ruby version is later, but I can't see why that would affect only the css.

If I look at the html source in Windows, under application.css, I can see the different elements loaded in, one after another. Everything appears properly. However, the exact same code contains nothing on Ubuntu - just the application.css file, with require self and require tree.

There aren't any errors on the Firefox console or the terminal where I'm running rails s.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with a configuration I've made or some resource being unavailable, but without any errors, I have no idea where to start looking. Is this a Ubuntu vs Windows thing?

How do I get the css to work again?

Comment: Are you using any css template engine? Which rails version?

Comment: Rails Version is 3.2.6, and no css template engines that I know of. I am using bootstrap though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clean the asset cache from your server:

```
rake assets::clean
```

Try also run dos2unix or something - maybe the carriage returns from windows is evil on ubuntu?

```
find . -name -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Comment: I tried it on both Ubuntu and Windows (just to see if I was accidentally serving cached assets)...no change. Thanks for replying though. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Although when I started the server up again, on Windows, everything recompiled (each css file and js). Nothing like that on Ubuntu.